# Samba shared directory not found in windows machine

Tags: 14.04, networking, samba, file-sharing

I have followed plenty of tutorials for "Sharing folder from ubuntu to windows using samba using the command line". The whole installation though commands go will. But in the end, When I start to access the shared folder from ubuntu through windows, the network places do show the folder. Does samba require a wired network? It is not working on wifi?

Answer (score 0):

As long as your two machines are on the same network it should work fine otherwise you might need to do port forwarding.